# how to make div border wrap around text, but still be block?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am making a chat application with angular and bootstrap for practice.
Trying to make div border wrap around the text like the iPhone message bubbles,
inline-block didn't seem to work.

relevant code:

```
  <div class="col-md-4 chatWindow">
    <div ng-show="activeFriend">
      <div class="activeFriendBox">Chat with {{activeFriend.name}}</div>

      <div class="messageList">
        <div class="messages"  
          ng-class="{ 'message-right': message.from === currentUser, 'message-left': message.from !==currentUser }" 
          ng-repeat='message in activeFriend.messages track by $index | orderBy:"timeStamp"'>
          <span>{{message.from}}</span>
          <span>{{message.message}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="sendMessage">
        <form ng-submit='sendMessage(messageText)' name='messageForm'>
          <input type='text' name='message' ng-model='messageText' required/>
          <input ng-disabled='!messageForm.$valid' type='submit' value='send'/>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.messages {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.message-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.message-left {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem?  your screenshot seems to show a rounded border around each message.

Comment: yeah but the border is going all the way past the text, i want it to wrap around however long the text is

Comment: `display: inline-block` works for me. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpQPGv

Answer (score 0):

You have to float the containing divs left and right, and then clear each one.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 chatWindow">
    <div class="activeFriendBox">Chat with {{ activeFriend.name }}</div>
    <div class="messageList">
        <div class="messages message-right">
            <p>Message from 1</p>
            <p>Message 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="messageList">
        <div class="messages message-left">
            <p>Message from 2</p>
            <p>Message 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sendMessage">
        <form ng-submit='sendMessage(messageText)' name='messageForm'>
            <input type='text' name='message' ng-model='messageText' required/>
            <input ng-disabled='!messageForm.$valid' type='submit' value='send'/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.messages {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.message-right {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
}

.message-left {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}

.sendMessage {
    clear: both;
}

.col-md-4 {
    width: 33%;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jcmorris/m2a3Lrxv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i figured it out, i had to put the inline-block on the spans inside the div instead of the div itself

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 chatWindow">
      <div ng-show="activeFriend">
        <div class="activeFriendBox">Chat with {{activeFriend.name}}</div>

        <div class="messageList">
          <div class="message-wrap"
               ng-class="{ 'message-right': message.from === currentUser, 'message-left': message.from !==currentUser }"
               ng-repeat='message in activeFriend.messages track by $index | orderBy:"timeStamp"'>
            <div class="message">
              <span>{{message.from}}</span>
              <span>{{message.message}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sendMessage">
          <form ng-submit='sendMessage(messageText)' name='messageForm'>
            <input type='text' name='message' ng-model='messageText' required/>
            <input ng-disabled='!messageForm.$valid' type='submit' value='send'/>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/* Represents row (block you wanted) */
.message-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Represents message */
.message {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.message-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.message-left {
  text-align: left;
}
```